# Does the order of rules in ABNF matter?

Tags: parsing, abnf

Does the order of rules in [Augmented Backus-Naur Form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) matter?

In particular, are

```
a = b
b = c
```

and

```
b = c
a = b
```

the same?

What about

```
a = b
a =/ c
```

and

```
a =/ c
a = b
```

?

Would it be possible to have a rule using `=/` without a rule of the same name using `=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of. While it may make no difference regarding the result, you should always define your rule-sets in a way that the rules it depends on itself are already defined. When you are matching elements with certain rules, the order of the rules does of course influence the result.

ABNF doesn't allow you to *redefine* rule-sets at a later point, so it **must** always be the same. (ABNF is not a programing language, rules are not variables)

```
a = b
b = c
```

The example above would make no sense. In this short example it's apparent what this is supposed to mean, but in a long RFC these lines could be separated by a wall of text.

```
b = c
a = b
```

> Are those the same?

Yes, rules are not variables - but I'd recommend the second notation/order

```
a = b
a =/ c
```

`=/` defines an **incremental** alternative, or as specifically defined in the RFC:

> That is, an initial rule may match one or more alternatives, **with later rule definitions adding to the set of alternatives**.

There are cases where it might not matter, but it can't be assumed to always the case.

In your case it's the same as writing

```
a = b / c
```

`=/` shouldn't come before `=` for reasons of readability (and logic).

> Would it be possible to have a rule using =/ without a rule of the same name using =?

Not really, no. `a /= b` would simply be `a = b` then.

Comment: A bit of context I probably should have mentioned: I'm currently writing a parser for ABNF, which then generates a parser for the grammar defined by it. I'm not interested in best practices, but more in what is technically possible. The reordering is of particular interest to me, because reordering of rules could make the parser generation easier for me.

Comment: I see no problem in reordering the rules to be defined before any appened rules (like in your first example) - since it should already have been done by the author. The only difference the order can (should) make is the order of results - **if** you have multiple appended rules and **if** that is a concern.

Comment: One example of rules that are defined before the rules that use them is when you have a lot of short rules and list them alphabetically or by category. [The ABNF's ABNF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234#section-4) itself and [Appendix B](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234#appendix-B) (Core Rules) do that too.

Comment: I knew you could use rules that are defined later. In fact, I actually prefer that, because it makes the 'higher-level' rules to appear at the top. I was only uncertain whether reordering could change semantics.